# Why am I getting "The modifier 'virtual' is not valid for this item" error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I'm trying to create mvc application with model below: (the code is large. I think it will be more understandable for you)

```
public class Job
{
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Job> GetJobs()
    {
        List<Job> jobsList = new List<Job>();
        jobsList.Add(new Job { JobId = 1, Name = "Operator" });
        jobsList.Add(new Job { JobId = 2, Name = "Performer" });
        jobsList.Add(new Job { JobId = 3, Name = "Head" });
        return jobsList;
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public virtual int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    public virtual Job Job;
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Passport { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Comments { get; set; }
}

public class PersonPaidTo : Person
{
    [Key]
    public override int PersonId { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Head : Person
{
    [Key]
    public override int PersonId { get; set; }
    public Job Job { get; set; }
    public Head()
    {
        Job.Id = 3;
    }
}
```

I have an error in class `Person` in the field `Job`:

> The modifier 'virtual' is not valid for this item

Answer (score 39):

Yes, this code is invalid:

```
public virtual Job Job;
```

That's declaring a *field*, and fields can't be virtual. You either want it to be a property:

```
public virtual Job Job { get; set; }
```

Or just a field:

```
// Ick, public field!
public Job Job;
```

(My guess is that you want the former, but both are valid C#.)

Comment: and one more question^ what will be with lazy loading if i don't put virtual keyword (var 3)

Comment: yes, both are correct. i choose the second because it includes Lazy Loading. best regards

Comment: If this answer helped you solve the problem you were having you should consider [`marking it as the answer`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I'm sure Jon would suffer greatly from the lost potential rep

Answer (score 2):

The right way to make the field private and expose it with public property.

```
//Field
private Job job;

//Property
public virtual Job Job
    {
        get { return job; }
        set { job= value; }
    }
```